# Как можно изменить в вызываемом диве текст?

Tags: html, jquery

У меня есть несколько дивов и нужно через функцию изменить текст в диве.
[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/68qLjwv1/1/)

```
$(this).text(id)
```

Пытаюсь так изменить код. Но не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример добавления текста по событию:

```js
$('.change-text').on('click', () => {
  const text = prompt('Новый текст:');
  $('.ct-text').text(text);
});
```

```css
.ct-pre:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  user-select:none;
  color: green;
}
.ct-text{
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change-text">
  <p class="ct-pre">Добавить текст</p>
  <p class="ct-text"></p>
</div>
```

Аналогично с функцией `load`:

```js
$(function(){
    $('div[onload]').trigger('onload');
});

function load(self,text) {
  $(self).text(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onload="load(this,'2324')">
html
</div>
<div onload="load(this,'234')">
html
</div>
<div onload="load(this,'24')">
html
</div>
<div onload="load(this,'2')">
html
</div>
```